# php is not detecting all empty fields

Tags: php

I've got the following line of code in PHP at the top of the page making sure all form fields have content in them and not submitted empty...

---

```
if(!isset($_POST['name'])) { $err_name = 1; }

    if (!isset($_POST['phone'])) { $err_phone = 1; }

    if (!isset($_POST['email'])) { $err_email = 1; }

    if ((!isset($_POST['serve'])) && ($_POST['other'] == "")) { $err_serve = 1; }
```

---

name is a text input

email is a text input

phone is a text input

serve is a checkbox array

other is a text input

---

Then below that I've got the following lines which allow the php code to continue if there are no errors (above)

---

```
 if (($err_name != 1) && ($err_phone != 1) && ($err_email != 1) && ($err_serve != 1)) { 

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
    $serve = $_POST['serve'];
    $other = $_POST['other'];
```

---

Then I've got this next to each form field...

---

```
<?php if ($err_name == 1) { echo '<font color="red">Name cannot be empty</font>'; } ?>

<?php if ($err_phone == 1) { echo '<br /><font color="red">Phone cannot be empty</font>'; } ?>

<?php if ($err_email == 1) { echo '<font color="red">Email cannot be empty</font>'; } ?>

<?php if($err_serve == 1) { echo '<br /><font color="red">You must choose at least 1 area to serve</font>'; } ?>
```

---

Can someone please help me figure out WHY its doing the following...

- if I take  `&& ($err_serve != 1)` out of the 2nd code, everything
  except phone shows error messages
- if I leave it in, ONLY err_serve throws error.  The others are
  ignored and no error is displayed.
- Phone refuses to throw error messages.  This is everything where $_POST
  handling is in the php.

***Note that all tests are done by submitting a completely empty form***

Comment: it's because you're using `isset()` to set the error condition. Empty text fields are still set and sent with the form, but not unchecked checkboxes.

Comment: show the form. use empty. and unchecked checkboxes are the only form elements not sent to the server

Comment: What's wrong with trying to evaluate the var like if($var) {true/false} ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values will be *set* whether or not they are *filled* with a value. If it's an empty value, it's still a value.

Instead of using `isset()`, use `empty()`. It checks both if:

1. The value exists at all
2. The value is something other than 0, an empty string, false, etc.

The reason it works for the checkbox, is because when a checkbox is not checked, the browser does not send the value *at all*. This is contrary to text fields. A browser *will* send the value of a text field whether or not it's empty.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I thought I had tried empty as well; however, apparently I didn't change them all to empty.  Worked perfectly!